# Is there a name for a building that produces potions?

Tags: single-word-requests, toponyms

A few friends and I are developing a game that involves producing potions, however we're finding it hard to think of the name for a building suited to producing potions specifically.

Some names we have thought of include:

- Workshop
- Factory (This seems like more of a modern term, which goes against the setting of our game)
- Brewery
- Laboratory
- Pharmacy

Does anybody know if there a more suitable name that we can use?

Comment: You could try **Apothecary**, it's an archaic equivalent of 'Pharmacy' and probably more suited to mixing potions than medicines (but what's the difference?).

Comment: As far as I'm aware, historically "potions" and other drugs were made, stored, and sold all in the same building. Thus, the words I am aware of cover a place where all three were done.

Comment: An *apothecary* would make and sell his own medicines, many of which would be his own concoctions. They could be pills, tinctures, lotions, poultices, etc.

Comment: FWIW - Robert Browning's chilling dramatic monologue "The Laboratory" describes just such an establishment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was mentioned in the comments, and I agree: **apothecary** is probably your best bet.

> 1. a druggist; a pharmacist.
> 2. a pharmacy or drugstore.

[(dictionary.com)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/apothecary)

It can be used to describe either the place itself or the person who runs the place. Coupled with it's medieval etymology, it should give you the feel that you're looking for.